# Постоянное выполнение операции сложения, каким образом лучше всего реализовать?

Tags: python, django

Перейду сразу к делу.

Имеется сайт, на котором могут находиться потенциально большое количество пользователей (более тысячи, например).
И каждый пользователь имеет определённый "счётчик", который увеличивается на определённую сумму **независимо от того, находится ли пользователь в онлайне или нет**.

Так же, при этом, эта сумма должна **постоянно храниться в базе в актуальном виде.**

Так каким же образом такое можно реализовать? Реализуемо ли это вообще? Масштабируемо ли?

Я слышал о таком пакете, как **celery**, пойдёт ли он для этой задачи? Или, может, такая задача решается как-то по другому?

Comment: Из постановки вовсе не очевидно, что сумма должна постоянно храниться в базе в актуальном виде. Как насчёт вычисляемого поля вроде `начальное значение + прошедшее_время * скорость_счёта` ?

Comment: Тоже думал о таком варианте. Получается, что значение в базе надо будет обновлять только тогда, когда пользователь входит в онлайн?

Comment: Да, только само значение держать в базе не обязательно, только параметры для его вычисления.

Comment: @Aquinary значение в базе вообще обновлять не надо, надо вычислять значение на текущий момент тогда, когда оно понадобилось.

Comment: А как быть, если, например, скорость счёта может меняться? Например, первые 100 секунд скорость счёта == 1, вторые 100 секунд скорость счёта == 2. В итоге должна получиться сумма в 300

Comment: `скорость счёта может меняться?` Если закон известен, то вычислить, наверное, будет нетрудно. Если изменения происходят ввиду какого-то события (в том числе по таймеру/времени), то  по наступлению этого события вычисляется по текущему закону счётчик, записывается как новое базовое значение.

Answer (score 0):

Решил эту задачу следующим образом.

Как только пользователь делает что-то на странице, то он записывает значение текущего timestamp в БД. После того, как он обновляет страницу, код хватает timestamp во время обновления этой страницы и высчитывает разницу. После этого разница перемножается на скорость счёта и суммируется с текущем счётчиком, обновляя значение. В конце timestamp в БД перезаписывается новым значением.

Минус такого решения - если скорость счёта может меняться в тот момент, когда пользователь в оффлайне, то он получит сумму в зависимости от того, в какой момент времени зайдёт на страницу.

Answer (score -1):

1. Коннектимся к БД
2. Начинаем бесконечный цикл:
3. Выполняем обращение к БД вроде: "UPDATE users_list SET sum_field=sum_field+1 WHERE что-то;"
4. sleep(Длительность паузы)

Comment: И пусть работает железный конь без  передыху? Если не ошибаюсь, это называется поллинг. Хорошо ли применять его для такой задачи невеликой значимости?

Comment: @MBo *Если не ошибаюсь, это называется поллинг.* - Вы ошибаетесь. Поллинг - это когда опрос. Само слово поллинг и означает - опрос. Здесь ничего не опрашивается. Не понял вопрос про "хорошесть". SQL сервер Вы и так используете. И если Вам нужно раз в 10 секунд увеличить все счётчики на единицу, то это означает, что раз в 10 секунд надо все эти счётчики увеличивать. Волшебным образом, сами они никак не изменятся.